# How to validate the direct function call in nestjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, apache-kafka, nestjs

I am trying to send a direct function call, and I set the DTO, but not work.
here is the code (Send is my DTO) in my controller:

```
 @Post('/Send')
  async SendE(body: Send) {
    const mail = await this.messageProducer.SendMessage(body);
    return mail;
  }
```

I make a direct call to SendE function here:

```
  @MessagePattern('Notification')
  async readMessage(@Payload() message: any, @Ctx() context: KafkaContext) {
    const messageString = JSON.stringify(context.getMessage().value);
    const toJson = JSON.parse(messageString);
    await this.SendE(toJson);
  }
```

I want the "Send" DTO can validate the "toJson", but it does not work.
here is what my DTO looks like:

```
export class Send{
  @IsString()
  @ApiProperty({ required: true })
  MessageID: string;
  }
```

here is what the toJson looks like:

```
{
  MessageID: 123
}
```

If I send a non-string MessageID, it can pass the DTO.
Please help

Comment: Have you find any solutions since?

Answer (score -1):

You have to enable `validationPipe` to enable DTO's, There are 2 approaches according to the [docs of NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#validation). The `ValidationPipe` is exported from `@nestjs/common`.

## 1. Globally in your `main.ts`:

```
// validate incoming requests
app.useGlobalPipes(
  new ValidationPipe({
    transform: true,
  })
);
```

## 2. Per controller

```
@Post()
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
async create(@Body() createCatDto: CreateCatDto) {
  this.catsService.create(createCatDto);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am calling the SendE directly in the app, not from API. If I send the post request by using postman, the dto will work. but, if I call the function directly in the app, dto will not work even though I enable the validationPipe.